# Optimize/make better JQuery code for images slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've developed this basic image slider project:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({
      'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    close_box();
  });

  $('.backdrop').click(function() {
    close_box();
  });

 //SlideShow
 $('.next').click(function(){
  clickNext();
 });
 $('.prev').click(function(){
  clickPrev();
 });

});

function close_box() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 300, 'linear', function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
  });
}

//PREVIOUS
function clickPrev() {
 $('.img_1').css('display', 'block');
 //Move to the prev Image
 $('.img_2').css('display', 'none');
}

//NEXT
function clickNext() {
 $('.img_1').css('display', 'none');
 //Move to the next Image
 $('.img_2').css('display', 'block');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  display: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
 width: 40%;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
 .box {width: 98%;}
}

@media (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .box {width: 60%;}
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
 .box {width: 48%;}
}

.box img {
 width: 100%;
}

.box img:nth-child(2) {
 display: none;
}

.caption {
 padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.prev, .next {
 float: right;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Welcome Within</h1>
 <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>
 <div class="backdrop"></div>
 <div class="box">
   <img class="img_1" src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/wesal/wesal1.jpg" />
  <img class="img_2" src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/wesal/wesal2.jpg" />

   <div class="caption">
    <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
   <a href="#" class="prev">PREVIOUS</a>
   <p>This thing is called 'Caption'. Let me tell you:</p>
      <hr />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

See what I did there? 
the class is `display:none;` and when the user click on next or prev in jquery it will change the css to `display: block;`

Now this is a good start i guess, but what if I will add more images?
that would be funny if I keep doing that `display none` thing to every `nth:child()`, right?

I'm thinking of making that `click to change image` a function but I can't figure out how to make it so, so I wouldn't have to add css classes everytime!

Comment: You can use any of the many plugins available for this particular use. LIke these http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your jQuery more generic:

```
var imgVisible = $('.box > img:visible');
//SlideShow
$('.next').click(function(){
    $(imgVisible ).css('display', 'none');
    $(imgVisible ).next().css('display', 'block');
});
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $(imgVisible ).css('display', 'none');
    $(imgVisible ).prev().css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: I see, I kinda understand how this works. Thank you sir!